# How can the Earth's day increase and its rotation slow down at the same time?

Tags: earth, rotation, geophysics

I heard that the Earth rotation is slowing down, but I also heard the Earth's length of day is increasing.

Does the two theories go together or conflict with each other?

Comment: Yeah, question about Earth is totally too localized

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you slow down, it will take you longer to type a sentence, won't it?

When the Earth slows down (i.e. the speed of rotation is **decreasing**), it will take longer to complete a rotation, so the day is longer (i.e. the length is **increasing**).